# show modal after sent request in laravel controller

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog

I am trying to show an information with modal after redirection,My Controller Code is here:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $request = PartRequestMain::Create($input);
    return Redirect()->back()->with('error_code',5);
}
```

And I have Blade such as this:

```
@if( Session::get('error_code') == 5)
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#accept-modal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
@endif
<div id="accept-modal" class="ui modal">
    <div class="header">changed</div>
</div>
....
```

Now When I store My inputs,redirected back but don't show modal.
How I can solved this?

Comment: Have you checked if Session::get('error_code') actually has the value 5?

Comment: @MrEvers when I add `<div style="display: none" id="add-form-message" class="ui message success"></div>` in my blade this model showed but this page show again in div

Comment: Just echo the variable {{Session::get('error_code')}} and see what value it is.

Comment: @MrEvers when I add this code `@if(Session::get('error_code') == 5)
   <h1>hello</h1>
@endif` But don't print anything

Comment: @MrEvers Nothing is printed

Comment: That means Session::get('error_code') isn't 5 or maybe doesn't even exist. Try
`@if(session()->has('error_code'))  {{ session()->get('error_code') }}`  
`@else No error code`  
`@endif`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195939/discussion-between-hanie-and-mrevers).